# Match file and line number with sed

Tags: regex, vim, sed

I have a string that looks like this:

```
app/views/pages/_my_events_for_ba.html.erb:11:    ba_mbn_programs = Program.ba_and_managed_bar.all(:conditions => "user_programs.user_id = #{current_user.id} and brand_id = #{brand.id}", :order => :name, :joins => [:user_programs], :select => "distinct programs.*")
```

I'm trying to isolate the line number `11` and the file name `app/views/pages/_my_events_for_ba.html.erb` so I can open vim with those arguments via `vim +11 app/views/pages/_my_events_for_ba.html.erb`.

However I'm not able to get the matches for sed working like the way I want.  My attempt works in vim's regex but not with sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*\):\([0-9]\+\).*/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: `-E` is not a `sed` option

Comment: it is for OSX, I believe it's the bsd equiv to `-r`

Comment: Works for me. Do you have a strange version of `sed`?

Comment: Your are using basic regex, not extended.

Comment: `:set efm=%f:%l:%m | cgetexpr getline('.') | copen`

Comment: @hek2mgl Even though not documented, GNU sed supports `-E` as well.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ah, never knew that.

Comment: On second thought, `gF` from Vim would do exactly what you want.  See `:h gF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{print $1, $2}'
```

A regex solution could look like this:

```
sed -r 's/([^:]*):([0-9]*):.*/\1 \2/'
```